# Función resizable jquery con 2 divs dinamicos

Tags: jquery, html5, css, jquery-ui

Tengo 2 `div`s que ocupan el 100% del ancho de la pantalla: uno con el 15% flotando a la izquierda y el otro con el 85 flotando a la derecha. Utilicé el método `resizable()` de jQuery UI para poder ajustar el ancho del primer `div` pero al cambiar su tamaño el segundo se desplaza hacia abajo

¿Hay alguna forma de que al cambiar el tamaño del primero el otro vaya ajustando su ancho también? Lo intenté modificando su CSS con un condicional, pero no logro captar el nuevo tamaño del `div` luego de hacer el resize.

Éste es mi código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".files-tree").resizable();

});
```

```css
div.files-tree{
  height: 100px;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #303030;
  float: left;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;;
  max-width: 30%;
}
div.work-area{
  height: 100px;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: #606060;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="files-tree"></div>
<div class="work-area"></div>
```

Comment: añade tu código para ver el problema

Comment: Post editado con el codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar `flex` para esto. La idea sería poner ambos `div` dentro de un contenedor con `display:flex` y luego al segundo `div` (el del 85%) le añadirías la propiedad `flex:1` quitándole el ancho. Al tener `flex:1` el ancho automáticamente será el ancho restante del contenedor.

Algo como esto:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".files-tree").resizable();
  
});
```

```css
div.contenedor {
  display:flex;
}
div.files-tree{
  height: 100px;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #303030;
  float: left;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;;
  max-width: 30%;
}
div.work-area{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #606060;
  float: right;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="files-tree"></div>
  <div class="work-area"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro, efectivamente de esa forma ha funcionado.